# how to fix 'AttributeError: module 'IPython' has no attribute 'utils'' while imporing my own module

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

I have made my own class in python, but while making an object it gives strange error "AttributeError: module 'IPython' has no attribute 'utils'". This error is coming from the import statement in the **init** function in my module. I am importing from moviepy.

I have tried writing the import statement outside the class. I am trying to make an importable package for my personal use.

```
class video_reader_writer:
def __init__(self,video_file):
    from moviepy.editor import ImageSequenceClip // error here
    from moviepy.audio.AudioClip import AudioArrayClip
    import numpy as np 
    ...
```

This is the stack trace :

```
    from moviepy.editor import ImageSequenceClip
  File "C:\Users\sagar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\moviepy\editor.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .video.io.html_tools import ipython_display
  File "C:\Users\sagar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\html_tools.py", line 20, in <module>
    from IPython.display import HTML
  File "C:\Users\sagar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "C:\Users\sagar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 25, in <module>
    from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
  File "C:\Users\sagar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\crashhandler.py", line 27, in <module>
    from IPython.core import ultratb
  File "C:\Users\sagar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 128, in <module>
    import IPython.utils.colorable as colorable
AttributeError: module 'IPython' has no attribute 'utils'
```

Comment: Do not import modules within functions or classes. It is considered unpythonic. Also, please include the complete error message. Your problem is happening _elsewhere_.

Comment: do all your imports on top of the file before anything else

Comment: [Possible dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40557294/seemingly-missing-ipython-module-trying-to-use-jupyter-notebook-with-anaconda).

Comment: @DYZ i have shifted the import statements outside the init function, now the error is showing on importing the class.

Comment: Please check the link that I provided above.

Comment: I get this error with AndroGuard when I run `androguard analyze app-debug.apk`